# Particle system is seen as black from certain angles

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, particle-system

I created a particle system that should act as a spaceship's vehicle fire.

[image]
[image]

I've added it in a node loaded from a COLLADA file (made with Blender):

```
let engine = _spaceship.childNode(withName: "Engine", recursively: false)!

let engine_pSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Engine", inDirectory: "art.scnassets")!
engine.addParticleSystem(engine_pSystem)
```

But the particle system looks black (literally like smoke) from certain angles, while from certain angles it looks normal (like in the scnp file of the image above). This video shows the problem: https://youtu.be/JvNe140C068

Comment: In the properties inspector (of the particle system shown in your screenshot) can you scroll down and screenshot the rest of the details? I have a suspicion your placard direction is not quite right.

Comment: @Confused Ok, I uploaded another screenshot.

Comment: try turning OFF "Enable black pass", and "Enable lighting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these settings, or similar to them...

[image]

Comment: What about this specifically fixed the problem?

Comment: No, but I don't have a setup to try this. I'd like to understand the underlying concept as opposed to trying random things and not understanding why they work.

Comment: You don't need a setup to try this. You can start with the SceneKit template, and nothing else. That's what this is. The question doesn't provide enough information (nothing about lighting, scene setup, cameras, backgrounds, objects, etc), hence the "try this..." @kevlar